# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to convert the following SQL statement to LINQ.

```
SELECT * FROM History WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ActionDate, 112) IN ('20221116');
```

This `ActionDate` field contains both date and time and I only want to compare dates in LINQ.

So first I run a simple LINQ query to get all dates from table and then store them in a list so I can pass them to next LINQ for comparison like above. Here's my list. This is just for example otherwise I am actually getting values from database.

```
var someDates = new List<string>() { "11/16/2022" };
```

Then I pass it to next LINQ query but it throws error.

```
db.MyTable.Where(u => someDates.Contains(u.ActionDate.ToShortDateString())).ToList();
```

**Error**

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method and this method cannot be translated into a store expression
```

If I use `AsEnumerable` then I get a different error.

```
db.MyTable.AsEnumerable().Where(u => someDates.Contains(u.ActionDate.ToShortDateString())).ToList();
```

**Error**

```
This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.
```

How do I fix this issue where I need to pas multiple date values to LINQ to pick only those records?

Comment: Please indicate what data type `ActionDate` is.

Comment: `datetime2(7)` in SQL Server

Comment: Don't convert database column values before filtering. Use a range check (between dates) and all your problems are gone and the query is sargable. That said, I can't imagine that the `AsEnumerable()` version throws that exception. There's something we don't see.

Comment: What I have understood so far that `AsEnumerable` only works for when LINQ is written as query expression and not lambda expression.

Comment: Define the word "works". Also, `db.MyTable` is neither. The error "This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities." only occurs if you use `DbFunctions` in LINQ-to-objects.

Answer (score 0):

So with `ActionDate` being a DateTime data type you could get results from your data table using something along the lines of:

```
var results = db.MyTable.Where(x=>x.ActionDate.Date == DateTime.Parse(<date_string>).Date);
```

Results should be a list of entries within the table where the dates match.
You may need to use `DateTime.Parse` with a Culture format provider in your solution to cope with dd/MM/yyyy and MM/dd/yyyy formats etc.

Comment: This lambda expression selects those entries that have matching dates (ignores the time) - just replace `<date_string>` with your formatted date string. Just be careful of Culture formats for strings (which you would need to be in any case). Was it not helpful?